# spl_object_hash matches, objects not identical

Tags: php, oop

I have two object variables in PHP, let's call them `$a` and `$b`. I assume they're both the same object. And, indeed, a call to `spl_object_hash()` confirms this, but they each have different properties.

When I run:

```
if(spl_object_hash($a) === spl_object_hash($b)){
    echo "SAME HASH\n";
}else{
    echo "DIFFERENT HASH\n";
}

if(print_r($a,TRUE) === print_r($b,TRUE)){
    echo "SAME PRINT_R\n";
}else{
    echo "DIFFERENT PRINT_R\n";
}

if($a === $b){
        echo "IDENTICAL";
    }else{
        echo "NOT IDENTICAL";
    }
```

I get:

```
SAME HASH
DIFFERENT PRINT_R
NOT IDENTICAL
```

This has got me baffled. When is the same object actually two different objects?

Comment: Here's the `var_dump` of both hashes.

    string(32) "0000000020d6b2fc000000007ad31222"
    string(32) "0000000020d6b2f0000000007ad31222"

Comment: I wonder as well why the hashes are identical. Is there anything that makes these objects special? Can you add the definition of the objects in question and their states?

Comment: And where did those variables come from? Can we reproduce it, or it would be too complicated?

Comment: Am I crazy?  Those hashes don't look the same to me.  In php, `===` evaluates to false for me when I compare the two strings.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to this question i would just like to add that the hash is unique as long long as the object is kept in memory. Otherwise the hash could be reused.

Comment: They /are/ not the same: look in the middle: d6b2fc vs d6b2f0.

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference between being the same object, and having the same properties.

```
$a = new stdClass("same", "parameters", 1337);
$b = new stdClass("same", "parameters", 1337);

var_dump($a == $b); //True
var_dump($a === $b); //False!

$b = $a;

var_dump($a === $b); //Now true.
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the PHP version and the operating system, PHP might cast the two compared hash strings to integers before comparing them (because they look numeric). Either because the resulting numbers are very large, or contain letters, the casting could result in data loss and thus lead to the same int value for both strings. Try this:

```
if ('X'.spl_object_hash($a) === 'X'.spl_object_hash($b)) { ...
```

Comment: Your argument is invalid with strict comparison.