# With php finding out if variable is this exact class instance

Tags: php, class, this

I have run into trouble figuring out how to compare two variables which might contain the exact same class instance.

An abstract class (part of which is shown below) has a method fetch_mother() designed to identify the object that should contain it and return that or simply return itself because it is at the bottom of the stack. In theory, that stack should be no more than 5 deep.

Most instances represent things like categories.

With the get get_full_path() method:

Expected output was: [siteurl] /system/drafts/example-one/also-dev-notes/

Actual output was: [siteurl]  /drafts/drafts/[snip]/drafts/drafts/example-one/also-dev-notes/

Which means that the sanity check kicks in and breaks a loop. It also means that I have not correctly tested for the returned object being the same as `$this`.

How can I confirm is `$var===$this`?

Code where the problem takes place:

```
<?php
namespace modules\content\classes;
use modules\core\interfaces as i;
use modules\core\classes as c;

abstract class content_object extends c\module_lib {

    // vars
    // ...
    protected $mother;
    protected $map

    // ... code ...

    public function get_object_map(){
        return $this->map;
    }

    /**
     * Get the stream holding this item
     * @return \modules\content\classes\error|\modules\content\classes\content_object 
     */
    public function &fetch_mother(){
        if(isset($this->mother) && is_object($this->mother)){
            return $this->mother;
        }
        $mother = $this->module()->find_object_stream($this);
        if(!($mother instanceof \modules\core\error) && is_object($mother) && $mother != $this){
            $this->mother = $mother;
            return $mother;
        }else{
            // I am my own mother ? \\
            return $this;
        }
    }

    protected function fetch_full_path_from_mother($path='',$sanity=10){
        $map = $this->get_object_map();
        $mother = $this->fetch_mother();
        $path = $map . '/' . $path;
        if($this==$mother || !is_object($mother) || $sanity<1){
            return $path;
        }
        $sanity--;
        return $mother->fetch_full_path_from_mother($path,$sanity);
    }

    public function get_full_path(){
        $home = $this->get_core()->factory()->get_config('home');
        return $home . $this->fetch_full_path_from_mother();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear? `===` does exactly what you want, it tests if the objects are the same instance.

Comment: That's what I thought but...

Comment: @Twifty nops does what he wants. `===` will only return true if the objects are the same (exactly the same).

Comment: @Lucas "The same instance" is exactly the same!

Comment: @MatthewBrown You can also try `spl_object_hash` which returns the memory address.

Comment: Regardless of `$var===$this` or $var==$this` the loop continues until `$sanity` reaches zero. It's very frustrating.

Comment: @MatthewBrown try this: `protected function fetch_full_path_from_mother($path='', &$sanity=10) {`

Comment: @MatthewBrown Are you sure `fetch_mother` is not returning null?

Comment: @Twifty if it were the !is_object($mother) condition would catch it.

Comment: @Twifty I added a condition of `spl_object_hash($mother)==spl_object_hash($this)` and continue to get the same output. I am officially mystified.

Comment: @Lucas the sanity check works. I put it in to stop a loop eating all the available memory.

Comment: UPDATE: The problem has been found - the module I was relying on was making a new instance from the same data. `$var!=$this` because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053471/spl-object-hash-matches-objects-not-identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is non-obvious.

```
<?php
$foo = $this;
if($foo==$this){
    echo 'It is';
}else{
    echo 'It is not';
}
```

The output of the above would be `It is`.

That's because if the two objects are the same instance then the == comparison would be enough to determine this.

Likewise (as per the comments) `spl_object_hash($mother)==spl_object_hash($this)` is also true **only** if it is the same object. However, if another object with the same properties were created the above would be false because they are separate objects.

This question and answers deals with that exact same topic: [spl_object_hash matches, objects not identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053471/spl-object-hash-matches-objects-not-identical)

The assumption in my question (which I did not see at first) is that the lookup function is acting as a factory and caching objects. The differential conclusion must be that a copy or second instance is being returned.

Thus, the problem must be with the `fetch_mother()` method.

(Further investigation did indeed show that this was the problem.)

Solutions include checking for matching properties (which in this case works as there are several unique fields pulled from the database) or comparing `print_r` output.

```
if(print_r($mother,true)==print_r($this,true)){
    // code
}
```

That particular solution is ugly, inelegant and not very reliable.

A better solution would be to implement an object cache higher up the stack. (Which is what I will be proposing).

TL;DR: Objects with identical properties are still not the same.